# Saving data through AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

Update:

I have replaced `<input type=submit to <button ... and also remove the form` tag from my html, after modifying my code i do not see it executing my JS and I have a debugger line in the code and it does not break....

I'm trying to POST data and I have all the code in placed and wired-up correctly (I believe) but when I try to Submit my page # My page gets refreshed, I don't see any event is firing and I have set `debugger` in the JS, and I do not see any JS error in developer tool

What I'm missing here apart from my code?

here is my code:

//HML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>

    <script src="../AppScripts/RequesterAdd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div ng-app="requesterAddModule" ng-controller="requesterAddController" class="container">

            <h2> add requester</h2>

            <div ng-show="ShowMessage">Record saved Successfully</div>

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>HostModel</h4>
                <hr />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>First Name:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="FirstName" required class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>Middle Name:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="MiddleName" required class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Middle Name" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>Last Name:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="LastName" required class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>eMail Address:</div>


                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="Email" required class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>Is Host Active:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Active" required class="control-label col-md-2" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnCreate" data-ng-click="addRequester_ClickEvent" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

//JS:

```
var requesterAddModule = angular.module("requesterAddModule", []);

requesterAddModule.factory('requesterAddService',
    ['$http', function ($http) {

        return {

            addRequester: function (reqesterData) {
                console.log(reqesterData);


                debugger;
                $http({
                    url: 'PersistRequester',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: reqesterData
                }).then (function (response) {
                    if (response !== 'undefined' && typeof(response) == 'object') {
                        window.location.href = '/'
                    }
                },
                function(response) {
                    //failed
                    }
                );
            } 
        };

    }]);

requesterAddModule.controller('requesterAddController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'requesterAddService', function ($scope, $http, $window, requesterAddService) {

    $scope.addRequester_ClickEvent = function () {
        var req = {};
        debugger;
        req["FirstName"] = $scope.FirstName;
        req["MiddleName"] = $scope.MiddleName;
        req["LastName"] = $scope.LastName;
        req["Email"] = $scope.Email;
        req["Active"] = $scope.Active;

        requesterAddService.addRequester(req);
    }

}]);
```

//MVC Server side code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult PersistRequester(Requester requester)
        {
            var req = requester;

            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
           // {
                req.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                db.Requesters.Add(requester);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { Status = "Success" });

            //}

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a form without a method and action which will by default post to the current url. I would highly recommend not to use a form or at least not using an `<input type="submit" />` which will default in all the browsers to submit the form.

You're clearly using Bootstrap 3 here so why not just remove the form tag and the submit button and replace it with another element which will not trigger the form post and style it with `class="btn btn-primary"`. Some could argue against this practise along the graceful degradation guidelines but since this particular form is not built from ground up to support the non-js scenario, it is best not to allow browser submit at all.

Also, in your service where you're doing the actual post, you specifically tell the page to reload.

```
if (response !== 'undefined' && typeof(response) == 'object') {
    window.location.href = '/'
}
```

You should pass this data back to the viewmodel so that the view can re-render and display the response.

If you change the url, the view state is lost and the page will simply render again to the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

instead line

```
<input type="submit" id="btnCreate" data-ng-click="addRequester_ClickEvent" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

please do

```
<button  id="btnCreate" data-ng-click="addRequester_ClickEvent()" class="btn btn-primary" >Create</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested and is working for me replace:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnCreate" data-ng-click="addRequester_ClickEvent" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

with

```
 <button  id="btnCreate" data-ng-click="addRequester_ClickEvent()" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" >submit</button>
```

and I've change a bit your service to :

```
requesterAddModule.factory('requesterAddService',
    ['$http', function ($http)
    {

        return {

            addRequester: function (reqesterData)
            {
                console.log(reqesterData);


                debugger;
                $http.post('PersistRequester', reqesterData).then(function (response)
                {
                    if (response !== 'undefined' && typeof (response) == 'object') {
                        window.location.href = '/'
                    }
                },
                function (response)
                {
                    //failed
                }
                );
            }
        };

    }]);
```

it's posting to /home/PersistRequester if method  'PersistRequester' exist in other controller ie : foo controller change

```
$http.post('PersistRequester', reqesterData).then(function (response)
```

to  `$http.post('foo/PersistRequester', reqesterData).then(function (response)`